# Loading json file into snowflake with Kafka Connector

Tags: arrays, json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, flatten

i'm loading a json file through kafka connector, so the connector is creating an internal stage, pipe and destination table with multiple VARIANT data type columns.

The json has a specific attributes that are created like this:

```
"data_1_attribute": [
        {
            "data_1_id": {
                "data_1": "1111",
                "data_2": 1
            },
            "data_2_id": null
        },
        ...
    ],
    "data_2_attribute": {
        "data_3_id": 111111,
        "data_4_id": "XXXXX",
        "data_5_id": [
            {
                "data_3": 111
            },
            {
                "data_4": 111
            }
        ],
        "data_6_id": [
            {
                "data_5": 222,
                "data_6": "YYY"
            }
        ],
        "data_7_id": [
            {
                "data_7": 333,
                "data_8": "ZZZ"
            },
            ...
        ]
    }
```

The main difference between data_1_attribute and data_2_attribute is that 1 is identified as a single object ("data_2_attribute": { ) and this is understood in a correct way by the kafka connector, but the first attribute ("data_1_attribute": [ ) i think is understood as an array of objects and when the VARIANT column is create, shows me the data like this

```
[
  "{\"data_1_id\":{\"data_2\":1,\"data_1\":"1111"},\"data_2_id\":null}"
]
```

Where if i do a lateral flatten the result in the VALUE column is:

```
"{\"data_1_id\":{\"data_2\":1,\"data_1\":"1111"},\"data_2_id\":null}"
```

And i don't know how to access and flatten this information.

I was trying to used an ARRAY_FLATTEN but i don't understand how to use it, any thoughts? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `PARSE_JSON` for `record_content` column, this should fix your issue.

```
SELECT PARSE_JSON(record_content) ....
```

Comment: Thank you very much @demircioglu! i applied the parse_json to the string column value of the lateral flatten result and now i can obtain every atribute of the json column as a new column, thanks!